# How can I stop my blog from trying to use SSL?

Tags: https, security-certificate

I noticed yesterday that my Avg Visit Duration for users on Androids plummeted on 13th September. So I looked into it and found that Android users were being sent a warning message when they tried to access my blog, and thus, leaving immediately.

I spoke to BlueHost about it last night and the guy told me that my site was trying to use SSL when I'm only using the shared SSL certificate. Is there any way I can stop it from trying to do this? I've noticed that my Google Analytics code has 'https' in it. Is that what's causing this problem? There's no other 'https' in the source code.

(I should add that GA has been installed for over a month, so it's unlikely that that's what caused the crash on 13th September.)

The blog I need help with is arbitrarynonsense.com - obviously any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have checked your website from Poland and the connection is not encrypted at all. Your Analytics code does not have "https" added automatically, it just adds it when the page itself is being encrypted. Which is a correct behavior.

Are you sure you still have this issue?

Comment: There's no way you can prevent the warning once a user is requesting an https URL other than by obtaining a correct SSL certificate (these can be had for free or for as cheaply as $10/year so why not?) so your best bet would be to find out why these users are requesting the page over SSL.

Answer (score 1):

You have an image in your source code that you are calling via https:

```
background-image: url('https://arbitrarynonsense.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/dry-and-cracked-desert-walp-tw20112.png'
```

This is most likey the reason why the warning is coming up, not the https in the tracking code as that i always there regardless.